# Will a trophy 'trigger' done on another platform make it so the trophy is not possible to get on PS4?

Tags: achievements, genshin-impact

I play Genshin Impact on a few devices (PC/PS4/Mobile) and cool, my savegame transfers.

But I was wondering, the PS4 has trophies. But if I do something that would trigger a trophy while I'm playing on PC, for instance, will that trophy never be able to be unlocked on the PS4 version?

Like if I get past a 'story progress' trophy, will it unlock next time I  play PS4, or I needed to be playing it on PS4 to get it, and if I didn't well I'm screwed out of the trophy.

Comment: I haven't played for a while — last time I played, the PS4 version couldn't cross-play with any other platforms. They changed that?

Comment: @hobbs yes they did :)

Comment: @hobbs it’s a relatively recent change. Full-cross platform support was released in v2.0 in July 2021

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a quick version yes, all trophies auto pop and they added a platinum trophy to PS5 version. Note – This game has also been confirmed to auto pop the PS4 100% if you played the PS5 version first. This is done through the in-game log-in account system, which means you can transfer progress from PC, XBox, mobile etc. and still pop trophies.

Comment: I can also confirm that when I did something on the PC, I got a trophy the next time I logged into my PS4

Comment: your trophy progress is safe fredy